# took over something by threat

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say that someone, by force, pressures or by threatens someone and, took over something. What's the best way to say this in an informal and slang way.

> ***Wring*** his business(company he owns) out of him

> ***Squeeze*** his business out of him or ***Squeeze out*** his business from him

Comment: Squeeze or wring money out of him, perhaps. Not business. To wrest the business away from him.

Comment: Perhaps [hijack](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hijack).